# Не запускается корутина, пишет gameObject не активен

Tags: unity3d

Есть небольшая игра в стиле memory(нужно открыть все пары картинок).
Проблема в том, что при открытии 2х карт, генерируется исключение - объект(sceneController) не активен. Корутина запускается как раз при открытии 2х карт.
ActiveSelf возвращает true, ActiveInHierarchy дает false. Вот только почему не могу понять.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сорцы:

```
public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private TextMesh scoreLabel;

private MemoryCard _firstRevealed;
private MemoryCard _secondRevealed;

private ulong _score = 0;

public bool CanReveal
{
    get { return _secondRevealed == null; }
}

public void CardRevealed(MemoryCard card)
{
    if (_firstRevealed == null)
    {
        _firstRevealed = card;
    }
    else
    {
        _secondRevealed = card;
        Debug.Log(this.gameObject.activeInHierarchy); //false
        StartCoroutine(CheckMask()); //собственно корутина
    }
}

private IEnumerator CheckMask()
{
    if(_firstRevealed.ID == _secondRevealed.ID)
    {
        _score++;
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: " + _score;
    }
    else
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        _firstRevealed.Unreveal();
        _secondRevealed.Unreveal();
    }

    _firstRevealed = null;
    _secondRevealed = null;
}
}

public class CardGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private GameObject cardPrefab;
[SerializeField]
private int cardCountInHeight;
[SerializeField]
private int cardCountInWidth;
[SerializeField][Tooltip("Start position for first generate card for X coordinate")]
private float startPositionX;
[SerializeField][Tooltip("Start position for first generate card for Y coordinate")]
private float startPositionY;
[SerializeField][Tooltip("Distance between cards for X coordinate")]
private float offsetX;
[SerializeField][Tooltip("Distance between cards for Y coordinate")]
private float offsetY;
[SerializeField][Tooltip("Images what cards can have")]
private Sprite[] images;

private CardCreator _cardCreator = new CardCreator();

public int CardCountInHeight
{
    get { return cardCountInHeight; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            this.cardCountInHeight = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.cardCountInHeight = 1;
        }
    }
}

public int CardCountInWidth
{
    get { return cardCountInWidth; }
    set
    {
        if (value > 0)
        {
            this.cardCountInWidth = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.cardCountInWidth = 1;
        }
    }
}

void Start ()
{
}

void Update ()
{

}

/// <summary>
/// This method generate cards
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pairs"></param>
public void GenerateCards(int[] pairs)
{
    int[] shufflePairs = Shuffle(pairs);

    for (int i = 0; i < cardCountInHeight; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cardCountInWidth; j++)
        {
            GameObject cardInstance;

            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                cardInstance = _cardCreator.CreateCard(cardPrefab, new Vector3(startPositionX, startPositionY));
            }
            else
            {
                float posY = -(offsetY * i) + startPositionY;
                float posX = (offsetX * j) + startPositionX;
                cardInstance = _cardCreator.CreateCard(cardPrefab, new Vector3(posX, posY));
            }

            MemoryCard card = cardInstance.GetComponent<MemoryCard>();

            if (card == null)
            {
                throw new MissingComponentException
                    ("MemoryCard component must be attached to card prefab");
            }

            int index = j * cardCountInHeight + i;
            int id = shufflePairs[index];
            card.SetCardImage(id, images[id]);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// This method shuffle input array values and return new array with shuffle values.
/// Input array don't mutable
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arr">input array</param>
/// <returns>a new array with shuffle values</returns>
private int[] Shuffle(int[] arr)
{
    int[] result = arr.Clone() as int[];
    for (int k = 0; k < result.Length; k++)
    {
        int tmp = result[k];
        int rand = Random.Range(k, result.Length);
        result[k] = result[rand];
        result[rand] = tmp;
    }

    return result;
}
}  

public class MemoryCard : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
private GameObject backCard;
[SerializeField]
private SceneController sceneController;

private int _id;

public int ID
{
    get { return _id; }
    private set { this._id = value; }
}

void Start ()
{
    if (sceneController == null)
    {
        throw new MissingReferenceException("SceneController must be set in field");
    }
}

void Update ()
{

}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (backCard.activeSelf && sceneController.CanReveal)
    {
        backCard.SetActive(false);
        sceneController.CardRevealed(this);
    }
}

public void Unreveal()
{
    backCard.SetActive(true);
}

public void SetCardImage(int id, Sprite image)
{
    ID = id;
    GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = image;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая проблема может быть связана с тем, когда вы вызываете эту коротину. Жизненный цикл любого gameObject начинается с `Awake()`, потом `Start()`. После этого можно сказать, что инициализация GameObject закончилась. Если вы вызовете коротину до того, как закончится инициализация, то будет как раз ошибка, о которой вы пишете.

Подобная проблема описана [здесь](https://forum.unity.com/threads/coroutine-couldnt-be-started-because-the-the-game-object-is-inactive.275311/#post-2876355). Попробуйте дождаться конца инициализации объекта, а потом вызывать коротину. Например, это можно сделать, если завести булевый флаг isInitialized, добавив метод `Start()` присвоение этого флага в true. А перед вызовом коротины просто сделайте проверку `if(isInitialized)`

Comment: Вы правы, действительно метод Start() не отрабатывает, хотя обращение к объекту происходит при открытии первой карты, тогда как корутина запускается при открытии второй, карты открываются при щелчке мыши по ним, почему Start() не отрабатывает все равно не могу понять, нужно будет больше покопать по этой теме.